# What can I do to make playing a long D&D session more comfortable?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, session

Right now, we play D&D every other Saturday and spend between eight and eleven hours playing in one sitting.

We usually take a break for food, but eat it at the gaming table (Our wives sometimes hang out with us at this point).

The problem is, it's bring your own chair, and the best chair I have for this is a $25 Wal-Mart computer chair that has a low back and hard plastic armrests.

Ideally, I'd like to buy a better chair but right now there's not room for one in the budget.

I've considered wrapping thin pillows around the armrests and I think that's what I'll do.  I may couple that with standing up and taking a lap around the table every hour or so.

This got me thinking about all of the other things that go into a gaming session.
I've got this old chair mostly sorted out, but what else can be done to make long D&D sessions more comfortable?

Comment: This would be better asked somewhere the specializes in ergonomics or something. Its barely related to RP.

Comment: Fair enough.  If there's a SE for this I would want it migrated there.  There would be a higher quality of answers, probably.

Comment: Dude!  That is a seriously long session ...

Comment: @C. Ross. Yeah, my weekly Pathfinder Game generally runs for 6-7, but we've been known to go for 11+.

Comment: This might be more on topic if it didn't get turned into "specifically about my chair" - I think there's probably good more general advice on comfort for long games.

Comment: The question has been changed to reflect this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take breaks.  No chair is comfortable for 8-11 hours.  We used to do frisbee after big fights.  Now it's hacky sack.  It doesn't have to be a long break, just enough to get the blood flowing in your legs again.

Answer (score 11):

Keep the beer and snacks in a different room to the one you are using for gaming, that way you'll have to keep getting up for refills.

Answer (score 6):

Look at how to sit at a table.  There are plenty of postures that will reduce fatigue and save your back from injuries.  A towel on the back of your lombar region helps you maintain a good posture.

Exercise balls are a good source as well and $wife may have one you can borrow.  Again, you will need to learn how to sit on it but the additional bonus is that you can get exercise while doing RPG.

I would look at camping chairs like the [outwell comfort chair](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003K076RC) or anything like that.  Go to a out doors shop and try them.  There are plenty of models, they tend to be cheap, and some are quiet confiortable.  The added bonus is that you can use it in your next garden party!

Answer (score 6):

I find that I stand at the table for most of the session.  You have to be careful not to get into other people's space, and not to 'hover' over the map.. but getting up and walking around, helps me for long sessions.